# Converting MYSQL script to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to convert an existing MYSQL script into PDO. My MYSQL script works but my PDO version does not.

The aim of the script is to SELECT from the TABLE schedule certain UID's where UID's that are the same are chosen by the lowest alphabetical letter of their corresponding cif_stp_indicator.

So for example I am trying to locate UID number 'Y63553'. There are two UID's with this number. One has an cif_stp_indicator of 'N' and one with a cif_stp_indicator of 'O'. I wish to chose the UID with an STP  indicator of 'N'

so example data............

```
cif_train_uid               cif_stp_indicator            Other Data
   Y63553                          N                          x
   Z45789                          O                          x 
   T78456                          O                          x
   Y63553                          O                          x
```

I wish to choose the Y63553 with an cif_stp_indicator of 'N'

The below MYSQL script achieves that

```
 $cif_stp_indicator=null;
 $cif_train_uid='Y63553';


 $b="SELECT s1.cif_train_uid,s1.cif_stp_indicator,s1.schedule_start_date
 FROM schedule s1
 LEFT JOIN schedule s2
 ON (s1.cif_train_uid=s2.cif_train_uid AND s1.cif_stp_indicator>s2.cif_stp_indicator)
 WHERE s2.cif_stp_indicator is NULL AND s1.cif_train_uid='$cif_train_uid' ";

 $l=mysqli_query($mysql_link,$b);   

 if ($l) {

  while($berths=mysqli_fetch_array($l,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
  { 

  echo $berths['cif_train_uid'];    
  echo $berths['cif_stp_indicator'];

  }   
}
```

The below PDO script runs but it gives no results. I am sure its to do with the way the NULL part is configured as I can get the script to show both cif_train_uid's of Y63553 by removing the relevant parts of the script. I have had help from this forum to get this far with the PDO script and it is now just trying to understand why the NULL part of the script is not working. ie not reporting back Y63553 and N

```
 $cif_stp_indicator=null;
 $cif_train_uid='Y63553';

 $sql="SELECT s1.cif_train_uid,s1.cif_stp_indicator,s1.schedule_start_date
 FROM schedule s1
 LEFT JOIN schedule s2
 ON (s1.cif_train_uid=s2.cif_train_uid AND s1.cif_stp_indicator>s2.cif_stp_indicator)
 WHERE s2.cif_stp_indicator is NULL AND s1.cif_train_uid=:s1_cif_train_uid ";

 $movedata=$mysql_link->prepare($sql); 

 $movedata->bindValue(':s1_cif_train_uid',$cif_train_uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $movedata->execute();

 $array=$movedata->fetchAll();
 for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++){
 echo $array[$i]['cif_train_uid'];
 echo $array[$i]['cif_stp_indicator'];
 }
```

Code for connecting

```
try
{
$mysql_link= new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=db;charset=utf8",$username,$password);
$mysql_link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
$mysql_link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected Success";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($movedata as $row2) {
  echo $row2['cif_train_uid'];  
  echo $row2['cif_stp_indicator'];
}
```

With PDO you should either foreach as if it's an array... or fetchAll in an array and then loop through it as you would with any other array.

The alternative being:

```
$array = $movedata->fetchAll();
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++) {
  echo $array[$i]['cif_train_uid'];  
  echo $array[$i]['cif_stp_indicator'];
}
```

It's one of those weird things with PDO and foreach... it has a special function.. practical but confusing.

Comment: Thanks Dominique. Still not getting any results even with that change

Comment: I'll have a close look.. hang on.

Comment: will try the alternative

Comment: try adding $mysql_link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);right after your connection string definition,  it will give you some extra error info

Comment: Did you define $mysql_link the way you should for PDO?  it's not the same

Comment: $mysql_link = new PDO("mysql:host=xxxxxxxx.xxx;dbname=yyyyyyyyy", "user", "password");

Comment: Why do you use $movedata->bindValue(':s2_cif_stp_indicator',null, PDO::PARAM_INT); and not just put NULL in your query... no reason to make that an extra parameter... unless you intend to play with it later of course.

Comment: Have just added the connection data to my question

Comment: Think when I added NULL to the query it did not like it. Already included the extra error info

Comment: You can use NULL in your query... but you need to write "IS NULL" and not "= NULL"

Comment: In your previous query you had it right... that might be the problem... change it to IS NULL again inside the query and take off the extra parameter.

Comment: Just tried it - getting unexpected cif_stp_indicator syntax error.................WHERE cif_stp_indicator is NULL AND s1.cif_train_uid=:s1_cif_train_uid ";

Comment: s1.cif_stp_indicator is NULL  ??

Comment: You have to tell the query what table you want data from, as you're using the same table twice... now it's ambiguous.

Comment: Just tried s1 and still no result. will try s2 instead before updating code with s1 in question

Comment: In your original query you used s2... my mistake.. but your query has to be the same as the one that worked... don't let me throw you off!

Comment: my s1 was a silly hint to show how the system can get confused.. I should have been clear... sorry about that

Comment: Also, I don't know if it might cause problems but you might wanna put some spaces in your statement... "s1.cif_train_uid = :s1_cif_train_uid" instead of "s1.cif_train_uid=:s1_cif_train_uid"   := reminds me too much of programming C

Comment: Thanks Dominique. I've been ages on this and you've solved it

Comment: cool... a lot of small mistakes... but solved in the end... I'm glad.. thanks for accepting... enjoy your trains ;)